# Is sql injection possible in stored procedures with text param?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Im using such a query in my stored procedure

```
SET @Statement =
'SELECT Id,Title,Content,Status,ROW_NUMBER()
        OVER (ORDER BY ' + @Sort + ') AS StudentReport

         FROM YearBook

        WHERE ' + @Criteria + ')

         AS ArticleNumber

        WHERE StudentReport> ' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @StartRowIndex) + ' AND

        StudentReport<= (' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, @StartRowIndex + @MaximumRows);
```

Just want to know whether its possible to do sql injection to this stored procedure. If yes, how can i prevent it? Need Help !!!

Comment: Is that valid TSQL? Can you show a cutdown but working example of a SP that represents your concerns?

Comment: I've edited your question, is that what you mean? If so, how does your SP execute that SQL? Are `@Sort` and `@Criteria` parameters to the SP?

Comment: Generally, if you accept varchars and treat them as blocks of sql then you have one benefit and two problems. Your SP will be very flexible, because your SP is flexible it will be hard to make a consistent useful query plan for it, why have an SP, because it is so flexible I can use it to do things that you may not have intended, that would be an injection attack.

Comment: so, how does your SP execute the dynamically created query?

Comment: using C# code, im running the SP

Comment: Ok, if you build the statment in c#, including all the where clauses and the order, then use `SqlCommand` to perform the query ADO.NET will call `sp_executeSql` for you and you won't have an injection problem. SQL Server will also be able to reuse query plans for statements with a common structure. You should have parameters for `@StartRowIndex` and one for `@EndRowIndex` which you don't need to convert in the query.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's possible. Quite easy, even. Try setting

```
@Criteria = "\r\nGO\r\nexec sp_addlogin 'hacker', 'broken'\r\nGO";
```

The batch will product errors, but the part in between will run nevertheless so welcome your new login.

---

The correct way to do your query could be something like this.

```
CREATE PROC FindSomething
  @StartRowIndex int,
  @MaximumRows int,
  @Sort int, -- 1-4 representing the columns, say in a dropdown
  @Id int,
  @Content varchar(max),
  @Title varchar(max),
  @Status int
AS
SELECT Id,Title,Content,Status
FROM
(
    SELECT Id,Title,Content,Status,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY
               CASE when @Sort = 1 then Id
                    when @Sort = 4 then Status
                    end,
               CASE when @sort = 2 then Title
                    when @sort = 3 then Content
                    end) AS StudentReport
    FROM YearBook
    WHERE (@id is null or @id = Id)
      AND (@Content is null or @Content = Content)
      AND (@Title is null or @Title = Title)
      AND (@status is null or @Status = Status)
) Numbered
WHERE StudentReport >= @StartRowIndex
  AND StudentReport <= @StartRowIndex + @MaximumRows
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
GO
```

Read here on more about dynamic searching: [www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Note: I split up 1/4 and 2/3 in the sort because each branch of a CASE statement must produce the same type, or that is compatible. int/varchar is very bad mix to have in a case statement.

Comment: Isnt there any way to provide the criteria like group = 'b' or somethg like this to the stored procedure? I means to set an expression validator and prevent it?

Comment: I dont know much... Kindly ignore my mistakes

Comment: Does this mean, inplace of the Content placeholder, even if we pass a query, it will be treated only as a text, not as a query?

Comment: This is a good TSQL only approach, if you have different where clauses make different stored procedures. +1

Comment: The whole thing is a stored procedure. You pass only parameters to it, instead of making ad-hoc queries. It has 0.00% probability of sql injection.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the above is a string that you are building and then executing with `EXEC` or `sp_executesql` then **Yes**, SQL injection is possible.

How to prevent it depends on what you are trying to do. Perhaps you need to rethink your approach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will. You can still do things to help defend against it tho'

For example, `@Sort` is a column name, so you can escape that properly (and ensure that if someone tried to inject something into is it won't work, because it has been properly escaped. For that use [QUOTENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx).

```
QUOTENAME(@Sort)
```

`@Criteria` is more difficult because you are actually expecting a fragment on SQL code so it becomes very difficult to work out what is valid and what is malicious. You might want to reconsider what you are trying do do here. If you must use Criteria then ensure that the security model is set up so that only the application(s) that absolutely needs it has access to the stored proc that does this. Make sure that the validation in the application before it sends of the SQL to ensure that anything it is doing isn't going to be damaging.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to make a pretty generic search stored procedure with paging.  These are difficult to implement properly in t-sql only, and can become maintenance headaches down the road due to the branching logic, or additional supporting stored procedures you need to add...

I would start to look at other options outside of a pure sql approach.  Using an orm, or micro orm could help a lot.  Actually, take a look at what Sam Saffron came up with...

http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/09/05/Digging+ourselves+out+of+the+mess+Linq-2-SQL+created