# sqlParameters vs string.Format which is better for speed increase?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, ado.net

sqlParameters vs string.Format which is better for speed increase?

**Without assuming the security**

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbl_test VALUES(@a, @b);";
SqlParameter  SqlParameter[] sqlParameters = new SqlParameter[2];
sqlParameters[0] = new SqlParameter("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlParameters[0].Value = varA;
sqlParameters[1] = new SqlParameter("@b", SqlDbType.VarChar);
sqlParameters[1].Value = varB;
```

vs

```
string query = string.Format("INSERT INTO tbl_test VALUES({0},{1});", varA, varB);
cmd.CommandText = query;
```

Comment: Using the parameters is a secure way of doing things.
With the string you have a risk of SQL injections.  This does not answer your questions, but I would always go for the first option, since the seconds is frowned upon.

Comment: Using parameters is faster in almost all cases: there's one and the same SQL for RDMS to optimize, not many slightly different queries for each of values combinations

Comment: How much faster would anyone be than the other one? I do not think there would be any significant difference.

Comment: Nobody mentioned [racing horses](http://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using parameters is *faster* in almost all cases: there's *one and the same* SQL for RDMS to optimize:

```
  INSERT INTO tbl_test 
       VALUES(@a, @b)
```

So server can parse and optimize the query *once* and then just *run* it. On the contrary, if you don't use parameters, RDMS has to *parse and optimize* many slightly different queries like that:

```
  INSERT INTO tbl_test 
       VALUES(1, 2)
  ...
  INSERT INTO tbl_test 
       VALUES(3, 4)
  ...
  INSERT INTO tbl_test 
       VALUES(100, 101)
```

and that *constant parsing/optimizing* is time consuming.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , both are different things, 2nd one is prone to SQL injection, whereas 1st one prevents that.

Second, using parameters also allows SQL Server to take advantage of cached query plans.

For more info, refer to this link -- [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22025928/why-use-sqlparameter-and-not-embed-parameters)

Answer (score 1):

Using parameters is definitely faster.

- If you're using `string.Format`, the DB server will treat each and
  every statement as new one. Which means: The statement has to be
  compiled and optimized and then executed.
- For a query with
  parameters, compilation/optimization happens only once, then the
  result is cached, and when the next such statement arrives, the
  pre-compiled query will be reused.