# Read a specific row from database using a variable

Tags: c#, database, variables, row

I have troubles reading an specific row from database.

I have an integer `ni` and I want to read only this `ni` row from the SQL Server database (if ni = 3 I need to read the third row).

```
private void intrebarea(int ni)
{
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl", con);

    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Read();
}
```

I thought it is possible to use

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl WHERE id=ni", con);
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Any ideas, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best approach is to use [parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26159764/sqlparameters-vs-string-format-which-is-better-for-speed-increase): your query will be [faster](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/460caf4c-41ec-4bcb-9825-ba9671a1fffd/is-it-ever-more-efficient-to-use-sql-stringformat-rather-than-a-sqlcommand-with-parameters-?forum=csharpgeneral) and it will avoid SQL injection.

Take a look:

```
private void intrebarea(int ni)
{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from tbl Where Id = @Id", con);
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Id", System.Data.SqlDbType.Int)));
    cmd.Parameters["@Id"].Value = ni;
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    rdr.Read();
}
```

Comment: This is what I needed. Thak you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right you should use:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(string.Format("Select * from tbl where id={0}", ni), con);
```